# PHP failed to send email after recieving 354

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am trying to send an email via pure php code without login SMTP server, code as follows:

```
<?php
$from = "test@localhost";
$to = 'ayon@hyurl.com';
$domain = substr($to, strpos($to, '@')+1);
$dns = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);
$mx = $dns[0]['target'];
$message = "
HELO localhost
MAIL FROM: $from
RCPT TO: $to
DATA
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?ztK1xLXa0ru49iBNb2RQSFAgs8zQ8g==?=
From: $from
To: $to
Date: Mon, 03 Apr 2017 13:54:10 +0800
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain

SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ==
.
";
$server = fsockopen($mx, 25, $errno, $error, 10);
if($errno){
    echo $error;
}else{
    fputs($server, $message);
    while(!feof($server)) {
        echo fgets($server);
    }
    fclose($server);
}
```

After printing

```
220 bizmx8.qq.com MX QQ Mail Server
250 bizmx8.qq.com
250 Ok
250 Ok
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
```

the program hang up, anybody know why, how can I sent this email to the given address. Plus: I am very sure that my script use **\r\n** as line ending.

Comment: Please tell me why are you using this method, Why don't you use mail or any third party mailer service?

Comment: User third party mailer like [swift mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/download)

Comment: If you could just tell me how to solve this problem: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP's [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function it's possible.

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Take Below Reference for more :

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Configure Your SMTP Server Settings in `php.ini` file :

In `php.ini` Configuration would be like this:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
```

Add Your server name instead of `localhost`.

Comment: If you could just tell me how to solve this problem: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Comment: @Ayon, Updated Answer. Kindly check again.

Comment: What I want is to send email without SMTP server, apparently the php mail() function requires one.

Comment: @Ayon where are you running this code ? on localhost ?

Comment: yes, I run it on localhost, but it's not my concern now. I've already know how to send emails without login a SMTP server, and the solution is write a SMTP server myself, which is my code post above wanted to do, it acts like a SMTP server and send email directly to the recipient's server. The question is not what makes the program hung up, but the sequence that goes wrong, I cannot send all commands with the message to the recipient at the same time, because the remote server will not separate them, I have to wait and send each command separately after receiving data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Want to send email directly to a recipient, and without a SMTP server, there is only one solution. Normally, we send an email, the procedure goes like this:

> sender->sender's SMTP Server->recipient's SMTP Server->recipient

but we can cut down the sender->sender's SMTP Server process, directly send emails to the recipient's SMTP server. The whole message and commands we need to send is the same as sending to the sender's SMTP Server, but it must be in a proper order, that is

> ```
> send a command
> wait for response
> send another command
> ...
> ```

with this sequence, we can send email to any SMTP server, no matter it is the sender's or the receiver's.

Comment: Keep habbit of accepting answer once you find a solution, Regards.

Comment: I will not judge, because it may mislead other visitors.